# How to modify Azure VM firewall rule for remote desktop

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, windows-firewall

On an Azure VM I edited the Windows Firewall rule "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP" so that only our Remote IP address was allowed access. In order to do this I also had to select General > Action > Allow the connection if it is secure. For some reason, despite supplying the correct IP address, the connection dropped and I have been unable to logon since. I have tried the steps in http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIReenablingRemoteDesktopWithPowerShellAfterYouveBlockedItWithYourOwnFirewallRule.aspx to no avail.

How can I delete / recreate the default RDP firewall rule from Azure Powershell?

Comment: can you actually connect to the server via powershell remotely?

Comment: Yes, that part's fine. I've been trying with Get-NetFirewall etc. to no avail

Comment: did you try to simply disable windows firewall? Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetFirewallProfile –Enabled False

Comment: that could well do it; there are so many cmdlets it's hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer.

Powershell cmdlet to disable Windows Firewall:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetFirewallProfile –Enabled False
```

Then all you have to do is to connect and remove the problematic rule.